# How to customize the FullCalenderBundle by user [Symfony4]

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, fullcalendar, symfony4

I'm a beginner in symfony and, I want to customize the FullCalendar by the user. The user can only show his events. So how do I edit this script? :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev, next, today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
            },
            lazyFetching: true,
            navLinks: true,
            eventSources: [
                {
                    url: '/fc-load-events',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        filters: {}
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is JS code that is unrelated to Symfony. Maybe you can expand your question with an exampke what the output looks like and what you expect instead. Also you might want to show us what happens in the `/fc-load-events` call, as this might be useful for returning different data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the events from your database first. Then you can import them into that Full Calendar script.

You need to 1st setup a "One To Many" relationship between the User and Event entities. Then you can use something like this code, to have doctrine return all events that have a userId matching the active users id.

```
$return = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Events::class)->findBy(array('userid' => $user->getId()));
```

Finally you could use JsonResponse to return the events as json.

```
return new JsonResponse($return)
```

I'm happy to clean this answer up a bit more for you. But I need to know what you're really asking. I hope this helps, but it's the best I can do with such limited info to go on!

Comment: Thank you Brennan, you understand me, i got it and It works well.

Comment: I have another question,
I want every user(Role_admin) show the events of other by selecting a user in form added Above the calendar,

so how to FullCalenderListener.php read the request of form ?

Comment: So when an Admin looks at the calendar page, a form displays above the calendar which allows the admin to choose which users events to show on the calendar?

Comment: Yeah, I can show you how to do that. Do you mind creating a new question for this one, and I'll add my answer on to that one?

Displaying an admin only visible form above the Calendar is very easy. In your TWIG file create the form wherever you want it, and then wrap the form within this.  ```{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %} <form>....</form>{% endif %}```

Comment: You can find my new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882281/how-to-customize-the-data-of-fullcalenderbundle-symfony4